# `cargo build` fails with linking error "link.exe failed: exit code: 325595"

Tags: windows, linker, rust

I have a Rust project that compiles okay on Linux, macOS, and Windows 10.

I installed the following individual components on my Windows 7 computer today using the [Visual Studio Installer](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017):

- `VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop`

  - `Windows Universal CRT SDK` (Dependency)
  - `Windows 8.1 SDK` (Dependency)

After that, I installed Rust using a fresh `rustup-init.exe` from the [official website](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html).

When I run `cargo build` on my Rust project on the Windows 7 computer, it fails with the following message:

```
error: linking with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe\` failed: exit code: 325595.
```

---

Running `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe` all on its own with no arguments on my Windows 10 computer produces some "help" information, but on my Windows 7 computer, I get a window with the error message:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).  Click Ok to close the application.
```

---

My Google-Fu hasn't turned up any useful information.  I've tried:

- `sfc /scannow`
- ensure System32 doesn't have 32-bit DLLs
- ensure SysWOW64 doesn't have 64-bit DLLs

Comment: linked question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59171127/link-exe-not-found-error-while-running-on-windows-system-for-rust-program-is-vi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading the latest 64-bit runtime [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads), `link.exe` works on my Windows 7 computer.  I can now compile my Rust project.

I'm surprised that the Visual Studio Installer doesn't ensure that the necessary runtime components are installed for the 2015 toolset.

---

**Update:** [Stargateur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7076153/stargateur) pointed out that the Redistributable can be installed directly from the Visual Studio Installer.
It is the `Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable Update` individual component.

Comment: visual studio is not primary dev for C++, you need to check some option.

Comment: @Stargateur I don't understand your comment.

Comment: To install c++ redistributable visual studio has an option in the installer

Answer (score 36):

Changing the default linker solves this issue. My system is a 64 bit one but the linker was pointing to a 32 bit one.

This is also mentioned in the rust [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html#:%7E:text=you%E2%80%99ll%20need%20a%20linker%20of%20some%20kind)

```sh
 rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

Read [this](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/windows.html#:%7E:text=Or%20to%20choose%20the%2064%20bit%20GNU%20toolchain) for more explanation on why this happens.

By default, the configuration chose it for 32 bit so running the command given above will switch the linker for 64 bit.

Comment: It would be better to add some explain to your answer.

Comment: Sure! Let me add some links that explain why this happens!

Comment: @Pisomanik do you have any detail explaination, if you have shared here please

Answer (score 1):

It worked to me using the chocolatey via powershell to install rust again, try use `choco install rust`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you install `rustup` using [scoop](https://scoop.sh/#/) installing `rustup-gnu` instead of `rustup` worked for me on Windows 11:

```
scoop install main/rustup-gnu
```

Then:

```
cargo new hello
cargo run
```

https://scoop.sh/#/