# Can't find link.exe even after installing Microsoft Build Tools 2015

Tags: windows, rust

I want to build the environment of Rust, but when I install racer, the following error occurred

```
error: linker `link.exe` not found
```

I tried to install 'Microsoft Build Tools 2015' but I still can't succeed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe your question is answered by the answers of [`cargo build` fails with linking error “link.exe failed: exit code: 325595”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50337099/155423) or [Unable to compile Rust hello world on Windows: linker link.exe not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55603111/155423). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR: use a newer version of the tools. 2017+ should be good.

Comment: I tried to install 2017 and get following message :
'Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed'

Comment: What newer version have you installed?

Comment: I have installed visual studio 2017/2019,but only installed .net core...

Comment: What happens when you install the C / C++ build tools for the 2019 version (as suggested in the duplicate links)?

Comment: I need to install 'MSVC v142 – VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 ' right? 
Those translations are not the same during my installation process.....

Comment: Seems believable. I'd just pick whatever contains "C" or "C++"

Comment: Thank you so much. I install the  'MSVC v142 – VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 ' and it's work fine.