# link.exe not found error while running on windows system for rust program, is Visual C++ mandatory for Cargo?

Tags: rust

I am getting  link.exe not found issue , is there anything more i have to install?

> PS C:\Users\parik> cargo new test2
>        Created binary (application) `test2` project PS C:\Users\parik> cargo build error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `C:\Users\parik` or
>   any parent directory PS C:\Users\parik> cd test2 PS
>   C:\Users\parik\test2> cargo build    Compiling test2 v0.1.0
>   (C:\Users\parik\test2) error: linker `link.exe` not found   |   =
>   note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
>
> note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was
>   not found
>
> note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed
>   with the Visual C++ option
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> error: Could not compile `test2`.

Comment: Read the messages: `note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option`

Answer (score 11):

There are two existing Rust toolchain families provided for Windows:

- msvc
- gnu

**msvc** is the default, and as you realized, depends on a recent Visual C++ installation.

**gnu** on the other hand depends on GNU/MinGW-w64. It can be installed and made the default toolchain using:

```
$ rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

Comment: this fixed the issue, thanks :). I was using VS Code

Comment: Isn't this a workaround ? Shouldn't we use Windows C++ via Visual Studio with C++ enabled ?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal What do you call "Windows C++"? To answer the question, this answer provides a definite statement saying that MSVC++ is necessary to use the msvc Rust toolchain, but provides an alternative solution if not possible. In that regard, yes, the second part of the answer is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to install VC+ build tools so that rustc should be able to autodetect the helper files. Or you can go with the VS 2013 or 2015(for autodetection).
For more information please refer [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/problems-with-installing-rust-on-window).